# Plotting Logistic Equation Fit or many variables in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a logistic model fit, say `myfit` that I've saved. The data frame I'm using is in the format of (where the first column is the outcome).

```
  medical10 age female nonwhite   bmi smoked condxs insuredd smi2d
1         0  60      0        1 29.97      0      0        1     0
2         0  42      0        1 25.85      1      3        1     1
3         0  62      1        0 25.06      0      1        1     0
4         0  62      0        0 36.27      0      2        0     0
5         0  32      0        0 33.36      0      0        1     0
6         0  41      0        0 21.70      1      0        0     0
...
```

What I would like to do is to make a logistic plot (in this form: http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/logistic.html) for each combination of variables.

Since there are 8 variables, there are 2^8 permutations of having one variable on the x-axis while holding the other 7 constant. Is there a way I can automate the plot using ggplot2?

For instance, if 'x' was age, I would get the mean of bmi, and then pick 0 for female, 0 for nonwhite, 0 for smoked, 0 for condxs, 0 for insuredd and 0 for smi2d. I would then do a prediction and make a ggplot of x vs y.

However, this is quite tedious and I was hoping there was a better way?

Comment: You should use `fortify(myfit, mydata)`. Look at `?ggplot2::fortify`. Though you'd still need to create the right data.frame first...

Comment: Check your thinking: There are only 8 combinations of one variable on the x axis and holding 7 variables constant (but it's not clear what your y-variable might be given that description.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of anything particular in ggplot that will make this easy. But I did find a way (though it was more work than I was expecting. Perhaps others can improve. Anyway, first let's define a more useful set of sample data

```
N<-100
set.seed(15)
invlogit <- function(x) exp(x)/(exp(x)+1)
dd <- transform(data.frame(
    age=runif(N,30,60),
    female=sample(0:1, N, replace=T),
    white=sample(c("Y","N"), N, replace=T),
    bmi=rnorm(N,30,2)),
    medical=as.numeric(invlogit((-60+2*age-1.5*bmi+3*female)/10)>runif(N)))

fit<-glm(medical~. ,dd, family=binomial)
```

So now we have some data and a model. Now i'll define a helper function that will predict values for a single variable while holding the others at the mean value.

```
predictone<-function(fit, var, xlim=NULL, fix=list(), n=101, 
    xname=var, type="response") {

    tt <- terms(fit)
    vv <- as.list(attr(tt, "variables"))[-c(1,attr(tt, "response")+1)]
    vn <- sapply(vv, deparse)
    stopifnot(var %in% vn)
    others <- vn[vn != var]
    def<-lapply(others, function(x) {
        if(x %in% names(fix)) {
            if(is.factor(val)) {
                stopifnot(fix[[x]] %in% levels(val))
                val[val==fix[[x]]][1]
            } else {
                fix[[x]]    
            }
        } else {
            val <- fit$data[[x]]
            if(is.factor(val)) {
                val[val==names(sort(table(val))[1])][1]
            } else {
                mean(val)
            }
        }
    })

    if(is.factor(fit$data[[var]])) {
        newdata <- data.frame(def, unique(fit$data[[var]]))     
    } else {
        if(is.null(xlim)) {
            xlim <- range(fit$data[[var]])
        }
        newdata <- data.frame(def, seq(min(xlim), max(xlim), length.out=n)) 
    }
    names(newdata)<-c(others, var)
    pp<-data.frame(newdata[[var]], predict(fit,newdata, type=type))
    names(pp)<-c(xname, type)
    attr(pp,"fixed")<-setNames(def, others)
    pp
}
```

Basically this function exists to calculate the averages of all the other variables and then do the actual prediction. We can use it with the test data to make a bunch of plots with

```
plots<-lapply(names(dd)[1:4], function(x) {
    if(is.factor(dd[[x]])) {
        ggplot(predictone(fit, x), aes_string(x=x, y="response")) + geom_point()
    } else {
        ggplot(predictone(fit, x), aes_string(x=x, y="response")) + geom_line() 
    }
})

require(gridExtra)
do.call(grid.arrange,  plots)
```

which will return

[image]

Note that factors are treated differently than regular numeric values. When you code categorical variables with 0/1 R can't tell they are categorical so it doesn't do a good job of inferring the values which make sense. I would encourage you to convert 0/1 values to a proper factor variable.

Comment: -This is awesome!! If I wanted to add interaction terms, I'm assuming I would just add them to my design matrix?

Comment: You would use them in the formula you pass to your modeling function. I didn't explicitly test with interaction terms but in theory it should work.

Comment: Hm, you mean include them in the fit? No that doesn't work because 1) it's not in names(dd) and 2) it's not in vv in predictone. Atleast it wasn't when I tried it.

Comment: I have no idea what you tried. Were you expecting the x-axis to show the interaction? Because I have no idea what that would look like. I just meant the plots would take the interaction into account. It would help if you could be precise about exactly what you were expecting (on the x-axis/y-axis if you envisioned a new plot).

Comment: Apologies -- I see the confusion. I meant if I had an interaction term of age "female*white", assuming both variables were factors, then the x-axis would still be just 0,1. I agree however that is becoming hard to visualize and your answer is great. Just to double check your response is really the "predicted probability" coming from   pp<-data.frame(newdata[[var]], predict(fit,newdata, type=type))?

Comment: Yes. It's the result of `predict.glm(, type="response")`

Answer (score 3):

An update to the R `rms` package to be posted on CRAN on about 2015-01-01 includes a new function `ggplot.Predict` (called by `ggplot()`) that provides a general way to generate such curves using `ggplot2`, handling multiple moving variables, interactions, etc.   You can see some example usage at https://github.com/harrelfe/rms/blob/master/man/ggplot.Predict.Rd .  You can do all this with the current version of `rms` using `lattice` graphics and the `plot.Predict` function.